# how to get read permission for friends_games_activity

Tags: android, facebook

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = 
new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("friends_games_activity"));

Session.getActiveSession().requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

I am trying to get this permission, when I am logging in with my facebook android sdk, after login, I don't see a permission page asking for me to give "friends_games_activity" permission,

I am checking which permissions I have with this line of code

```
System.out.println(Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions());
```

and I don't see "friends_games_activity" permission, I have no idea why this is happening, thank you,

I am using API version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using API v2.0. All friends_* permissions was removed in API v2.0

Comment: so, there is no chance I am getting my friends score, which I try to get scores with this code,  new Request(
       session,
       "/app_id/scores",
       null,
       HttpMethod.GET,
       new Request.Callback() {
           public void onCompleted(Response response) {
               System.out.println("app " + response.getRawResponse());
           }
       }
   ).executeAsync();

Comment: According to the documentation /APP_ID/scores should return the scores for all your friends for your app. You would only need friends_games_activity if you want their score in all apps which you don't need.

Comment: so I don't need "friends_games_activity" permission for getting my friend's scores, are these lines of codes enough for me to get friends' score ?  new Request( session, "/app_id/scores", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() { public void onCompleted(Response response) { System.out.println("app " + response.getRawResponse()); } } ).executeAsync();